# What can I do if the sink tailpiece is too close to the wall?

Tags: sink, bathtub

I have a small Porcher brand, Elfe model, sink, whose tailpiece is only 4 inches [OC] from the finished wall. 
One solution is a non code compliant bottle trap, but is there a code compliant solution?
Are there any devices like a tight radius trap?

Comment: A P-trap doesn't have to necessarily look like a P to function.  You can twist the trap around a bit, to make it fit in tighter spots. [This trap](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YoPwg.jpg) for example, goes "forward", and then loops back to the outlet. Just don't do anything [like this](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/24839/33).

Comment: Right, as Tester101 illustrated. Even if the wall outlet occurs exactly behind the tailpiece, there should be just enough room to install a 45 ell to take the P-tap outlet out of line of the tailpiece and enabling the suggested twisting around of the trap's U-bend.